# Even though Facebook API returns 'code' 200 for some 'nodes', when accessing the webpage it return 404

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a web app that uses FB data for some FB posts. I have a bunch of post ids and am fetching the data related to them using batched requests. Then am showing a summary of each post (number of comments, shares, likes) and link to the actual FB page (https://www.facebook.com/). But clicking on the link shows a 404 page on FB!!

Example, the node_id, '69983322463_10152179775342464' will return data in the graph explorer. But when you access https://www.facebook.com/69983322463_10152179775342464 it returns 404!

In case my question is not clear:
GET https://graph.facebook.com/69983322463_10152179775342464?access_token={a valid access token} returns data.
But GET https://www.facebook.com/69983322463_10152179775342464 (with or without an access_token param) returns a 404

Is there some field in the API response that signifies that the page does not exist anymore?

Thanks,
mano

Comment: _“Example, the node_id, '69983322463_10152179775342464' will return data in the graph explorer. ”_ – and it also explicitly returns https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152179774922464&set=a.10151852575157464.1073741825.69983322463&type=1&relevant_count=1 as `link`, so why don’t you use _that_? That is perfectly accessible, no 404.

Comment: You can also use https://www.facebook.com/10152179774922464 if you like, that will redirect to basically the same URL as mentioned before.

Comment: CBroe, in this case `link` points to the FB post in question. However, for posts that share a 3rd party webpage, `link` points to the 3rd party page and not the FB post!

Answer (score 0):

This is because not every post is public. Only publicly available posts can be accessed directly.

For rest you need a **valid access token** to GET its details. When you tried the post id in graph api explorer it showed the result since an access token was applied.

So, you simply use a valid access token, may be any app access token (`app_id|app_secret`)- that never expires, and make the `/GET` request.

Eg: `\GET /69983322463_10152179775342464?access_token={app-access-token}`

Comment: Thanks for the response, Sahil. If its not a public page would it not be specified so in the 'privacy' property of the API response? Right now its value is {"value": ""}. An id that can be accessed both via the API and directly also has similar settings for the privacy property. So am inclined to think this is not the issue! The pages involved are FB posts by US senator accounts and afaik all of them are public!

Comment: Sorry I cant understand what you are trying to say, but this is what the issue is. You gotta try this first!

Comment: Sahil, I tried it with the a valid access_token from the browser and I still get a 404. But I get a successful response from the graph api using the same access_token.

Comment: Lol, you are not understanding the concept here. The api explorer uses the token, just copy that and write this is the browser: `https://graph.facebook.com/69983322463_10152179775342464?access_token={token-from-api-explorer}`

Comment: Sahil, am sorry if I was not clear in my last comment. I did exactly what you said and am getting a 404.

Comment: Of course you aren't doing this. Just for you, check this once: https://graph.facebook.com/69983322463_10152179775342464?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAK1rhL4sWhNmuZC0NklLnlpvNmsTRXJ6DaCa7HMIkscuBGaemsDMmqIJ5Hmu0GZCFk48sEDJVt2mtVFfnkjd9ZBjVW9veGuXXabqySAND9GaZC8Jh0VLvCNwZBvCkeBWQAYVOTDED7etV9iKQV7D9e49ZCRdLuSW8Hb8jCztD5eZBI2GXHzIbwZD . Have calm, read properly and then try!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51497/discussion-between-manokaran-k-and-sahil-mittal)